# scala - unit test - How to mock a class method inside a class

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mockito

I have a class in Scala that looks like this:

```
class A {
  private val b = new B()

  def doSomething() {
    b.someMethod();
  }
}
```

How can I unit test `doSomething()`? How can I mock `b` here?

I tried something like this:

```
val b = mock[B]
when(b.someMethod()).thenReturn(xx)
val class_to_test = new A()
class_to_test.doSomething()
```

I am using Mockito and MockitoSugar.

Comment: why doesn't your approach work?

Comment: I could not find a way to pass the mock b to the classToTest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your last code snippet is that `val b = mock[B]` is a different variable from the `b` field of your class. You can fix this by modifying the class to take `b` as an optional argument:

```
class A(b: B = new B) {
  def doSomething(): Unit = {
    b.someMethod()
  }
}
```

Now your test becomes:

```
val b = mock[B]
when(b.someMethod()).thenReturn(xx)
val classToTest = new A(b)
classToTest.doSomething()
```

This technique is called **Dependency Injection**. You can read more about it here: [What is dependency injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection)

---

If you don't want to expose `b` as a public constructor parameter, you can use a package-private constructor coupled with a public constructor or factory method that provides the default value of `b`:

```
class A private[myPackage](b: B) {
  def this() = this(new B)  // The public constructor doesn't expose b.

  def doSomething(): Unit = {
    b.someMethod()
  }
}
```

Then just make sure your tests are in the same package so they can still call the constructor that takes `b`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Both solutions worked! I can't upvote the solution because I am a newbie on SO